# Find max/min values of the sum of squares

Tags: optimization

How to find max/min values for the sum of squares:

$n_1^2 + n_2^2 + ... + n_i^2$

where

$n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_i = c$

Is it true that max value is always obtained when $n_1 = n_2 = ... = n_i$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$f(x_1,\cdots, x_n)=x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2$$
$$g(x_1,\cdots, x_n)=x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n-c=0$$
Using [Lagrange multiplier](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeMultiplier.html) ([also see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier))

$$2x_1=2x_2+2x_3=\cdots=2x_n$$
This implies that minima will always occur at
$$x_1=x_2=x_3=\cdots=x_n=\frac cn$$

$$f_{min}=\frac{c^2}{n}$$

Comment: Where should I start to find the maxima?

Comment: There is no maximum as you can include zero-sum numbers ($M$ and $-M$) of any magnitude.